# Clicked element scrolls to top after other elements slideUp JQuery

Tags: jquery

Trying to get Element to scroll to top after "open sections" slideUp(). If there is a section already open above $this element, the scroll animation scrolls past the top due to the slideUp() of previously opened element. Trying to correct this. .slideUp().finish() and .slideUp().stop(true,true) work, however the slideUp() is immediate and looks rather glitchy. Thoughts?

HTML

```
<div class='sectionContainer' data-section='1'>
    <div class='sectionTitle'>
    </div>
    <div class='section'>           
    </div>
</div>
<div class='sectionContainer' data-section='2'>
    <div class='sectionTitle'>
    </div>
    <div class='section'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='sectionContainer' data-section='3'>
    <div class='sectionTitle'>
    </div>
    <div class='section'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sectionTitle').click(function(i) {
        i.preventDefault();
        var section = $(this).attr('data-section');
        $('.section').not(section).slideUp('slow');
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).offset().top});
        $(section).slideDown('slow');               
    });    
});
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: So you want a sequence of three animations?

Comment: Basically. As stated, once a section is clicked, I'd like any open section that is not 'this' to close or 'slideUp', then the clicked '.sectionTitle' will move to the top and open it's respective section. It works when I add '.finish()' to the slideUp, however, it does not wait for the slideUp animation to complete. It simply hides the div and makes the experience feel rather glitchy. When finish() is taken away, the section slides up as it should, but the clicked Title moves to a top position relative to the closing section.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sectionTitle').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('active')) {
        $('.active .section').slideUp('slow');
        $('.sectionContainer').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().children('.section').slideDown('slow', function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(this).parent().offset().top - 69});
        });
    } else {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().children('.section').slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: The ".top - 69" in the animate function is to make up for the height of my navigation bar which is fixed to top.